# What does assembly jmp offset <label+offset> mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I used

```
objdump -M intel -d test
```

and

```
objdump -d test
```

to disassemble a very simple for loop with gcc 686-elf cross compiler. I In both cases, I get the following:

```
 d:   eb 11                   jmp    20 <loop+0x20>
```

The full dump (INTEL) is:

```
00000000 <loop>:
0:   55                      push   ebp
1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
3:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
6:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
d:   eb 11                   jmp    20 <loop+0x20>
f:   a1 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,ds:0x0
14:   83 c0 01                add    eax,0x1
17:   a3 00 00 00 00          mov    ds:0x0,eax
1c:   83 45 fc 01             add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x1
20:   83 7d fc 09             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x9
24:   7e e9                   jle    f <loop+0xf>
26:   90                      nop
27:   c9                      leave  
28:   c3                      ret
```

This makes sense if it is jumping to offset 20, from label loop which is at 0.

What is confusing me is the syntax. Why do I have two 20's?

```
20 <loop+0x20>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `jmp` is relative, not absolute.  So it's an *offset*, not an address.

Comment: I'll correct it. Thank you.

Comment: It's telling you how it arrived that that offset.

Comment: In `jmp 20 <loop+0x20>`, the `<loop+0x20>` is informational output provided by the disassembler. The `JMP` in this case is **relative to the end of the JMP instruction itself**. The next instruction is at 0xf so the assembler encoded the relative jump as +0x11 from the end of the jump. 0x11+0x0f = 0x20. You can see the relative encoding of 11 in the opcode output `eb 11`.

Comment: Side note `The full dump (AT&T) is` should probably read `The full dump (INTEL) is`

Comment: The informational part `<loop+0x20>` says that the destination of the jump is 0x20 bytes (32 decimal) from the beginning of the label `loop` (which is the beginning of the current function). It  is easy to see that 0x20 from beginning of loop is `20:   83 7d fc 09             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x9` (note that 20: at the beginning).

Comment: Michael, yes, I copied the INTEL syntax. Thank you for your correction. I would've marked your comment as the answer because you answered first. So that is why I see "0x11". Good to know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hex `20` is the jump target address. `loop+0x20` is meant to be helpful, but in this case it's not very. The disassembler found the symbolic address nearest to `20`. In this case it's `loop`. It re-computed `20` as an offset from that label. Since the label is at address `0`, this simplifies to `0+0x20`, which is `20`, which is equal to the target as you'd expect.

This representation is more helpful in other settings. For example, if a label `a` were for the base of an array of `int`s, then `<a+0x20>` would specify the 32nd byte of the array, which would be `a[8]`.

Comment: So the `<label+offset>` is not a valid syntax of x86 assembly, but just an additional info provided by the disassembler for users to read? Am I right?

Comment: I don't know for sure that some assembler somewhere wouldn't accept it. But the output of a disassembler is under no obligation to be valid input for any assembler. There is no single "valid syntax" because there are several.